# define custom scan operator

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to create my own scan operator in cub. It is working now but only for array sizes smaller than 1024 which makes me think that it only works for a block. Here is my code :

```
#include "cub/cub.cuh" 
using namespace cub;


typedef int mytype;

struct CustomMin
{
    template <typename T>
    __host__ __device__
    CUB_RUNTIME_FUNCTION __forceinline__
    mytype operator()(const T &a, const T &b) const {
        return (b < a) ? b : a;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int num_items = 512;       
    mytype *h_in;   
    mytype *h_out;         
    CustomMin    min_op;
    const size_t size = num_items * sizeof(mytype);
    h_in = (mytype*)malloc(size); 
    h_out = (mytype*)malloc(size); 
    mytype *d_in = NULL;
    cudaMalloc(&d_in, size);
    mytype *d_out = NULL;
    cudaMalloc(&d_out, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        h_in[i] = i;
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    void *d_temp_storage = NULL;
    size_t temp_storage_bytes = 0;
    DeviceScan::InclusiveScan(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, min_op, num_items);
    cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
    DeviceScan::InclusiveScan(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in, d_out, min_op, num_items);
    cudaMemcpy(h_out, d_out, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It always hangs for larger input sizes.

Comment: I can't compile this code.  Can you please include a complete code that I can compile without having to add anything or change anything.  For example your `mytype` is undefined, as is your `g_allocator`.    If you're not sure, then copy what you've posted into a new file and try to compile that.  Fix that so it compiles, then edit it back into the question.

Comment: Your previous code was hanging here:

`for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i *= 2) {`

Since `i` starts at 0, `i *= 2` never went anywhere.

The code you have now posted runs fine for me and does not hang, even if I change `num_items` to 2048.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I figured out if I compile the code on TitanX with sm_35 it will hang but it will work with sm_52. I guess that is CUB's problem.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'm using cuda 7.5 on linux. CUB is 1.4.2. nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_35 code.cu -o code

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the hang now, I think.  I had to change `num_items` from 512 to 2048.

Answer (score 2):

With CUB 1.4.1 I was able to reproduce the hang when compiling like this:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t25 t25.cu
```

after changing `num_items` in the posted code to 2048.

According to my testing, the issue appears to be fixed in [cub 1.5.1](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html).  Please update to the latest CUB version.